# MPI apparently deadlocking when more than 5 workers are used

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpi

I'm writing a python script that uses MPI to send unsorted arrays to workers, that will sort said arrays and return them sorted to master.

Running it with `mpirun -n 2 python mpi_sort.py` up to `mpirun -n 5 python mpi_sort.py` works as expected, except that the DIE message seems to get lost when the number of arrays is too large, and the workers never stop.

Running with more than 5 workers, the script stops very early on the execution. Usually the workers will get the first load of arrays, return to master, and never get any more work. I'm stumped as to why that happens.

To make it worse, if I reduce the size of the arrays or their number, more workers seem to do the job just fine.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ENV python
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI

NUMARRAYS = 1000
ARRAYSIZE = 10000

ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG = 1
WORK_TAG = 2
DIE_TAG = 3

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
status = MPI.Status()

# Master
if rank == 0:
    data = numpy.empty(ARRAYSIZE, dtype=numpy.int32)
    sorted_data = numpy.empty([NUMARRAYS, ARRAYSIZE], dtype=numpy.int32)
    sorted_arrays = 0

    while sorted_arrays < NUMARRAYS:
        print "[Master] Probing"
        comm.Recv(data, source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)
        print "[Master] Probed"

        dest = status.Get_source()
        print "[Master] got request for work from worker %d" % dest

        data = numpy.random.random_integers(0, ARRAYSIZE, ARRAYSIZE).astype(numpy.int32)
        print "[Master] sending work to Worker %d" % dest
        comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=dest, tag=WORK_TAG)
        print "[Master] sent work to Worker %d" % dest

        print "[Master] waiting for complete work from someone"
        comm.Recv([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)
        print "[Master] got results from Worker %d. Storing in line %d" % (status.Get_source(), sorted_arrays)
        sorted_data[sorted_arrays] = numpy.copy(data)
        numpy.savetxt("sample", data, newline=" ", fmt="%d")
        sorted_arrays += 1

    for dest in range(1, size):
        print "[Master] Telling Worker %d to DIE DIE DIE" % dest
        comm.Send(data, dest=dest, tag=DIE_TAG)

# Slave
else:
    # Ask for work
    data = numpy.empty(ARRAYSIZE, dtype=numpy.int32)
    while True:
        print "[Worker %d] asking for work" % rank
        comm.Send(data, dest=0, tag=ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG)
        print "[Worker %d] sent request for work" % rank

        comm.Recv(data, source=0, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)

        if status.Get_tag() == WORK_TAG:
            print "[Worker %d] got work" % rank

            print "[Worker %d] is sorting the array" % rank
            data.sort()
            print "[Worker %d] finished work. Sending it back" % rank
            comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=0, tag=ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG)
        else:
            print "[Worker %d] DIE DIE DIE" % rank
            break
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with mpi4py, but this looks like a classic MPI deadlock -- you're posting recieves before the message is sent, so MPI waits to recieve, but there's nothing to recieve since you haven't sent anything yet.  I assume mpi4py provides wrappers around MPI_Irecv as well?  If so, you might want to consider using that instead...

Comment: It looks that way to me, but why is it deadlocking with 6 workers, but not with 5?

Comment: For efficiency, some MPI implementations cache operations in interesting ways.  Perhaps the caching is dependent on the number of workers (although, usually I would expect a `send` to be cached implicitly, not a `recv` ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

There were a couple of deadlocks, like @mgilson suggested.

First, a worker would send work back, but the master would interpret that as a request for work, which the worker was no expecting.

Then, there was the kill message problem, which was similar. DIE messages would be sent to workers who were not expecting them.

The final solution is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ENV python
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI

NUMARRAYS = 100
ARRAYSIZE = 10000

ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG = 1
WORK_TAG = 2
WORK_DONE_TAG = 3
DIE_TAG = 4

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
status = MPI.Status()

# Master
if rank == 0:
    data = numpy.empty(ARRAYSIZE, dtype=numpy.int32)
    sorted_data = numpy.empty([NUMARRAYS, ARRAYSIZE], dtype=numpy.int32)
    sorted_arrays = 0
    dead_workers = 0

    while dead_workers < size - 1:
        print "[Master] Probing"
        comm.Recv([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)
        print "[Master] Probed"

        dest = status.Get_source()
        if status.Get_tag() == ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG:
            if sorted_arrays <= NUMARRAYS - 1:
                print "[Master] got request for work from worker %d" % dest

                data = numpy.random.random_integers(0, ARRAYSIZE, ARRAYSIZE).astype(numpy.int32)
                print "[Master] sending work to Worker %d" % dest
                comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=dest, tag=WORK_TAG)
                print "[Master] sent work to Worker %d" % dest
            else:
                # Someone did more work than they should have
                print "[Master] Telling worker %d to DIE DIE DIE" % dest
                comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=dest, tag=DIE_TAG)
                dead_workers += 1
                print "[Master] Already killed %d workers" % dead_workers

        elif status.Get_tag() == WORK_DONE_TAG:
            if sorted_arrays <= NUMARRAYS - 1:
                print "[Master] got results from Worker %d. Storing in line %d" % (status.Get_source(), sorted_arrays)
                sorted_data[sorted_arrays] = numpy.copy(data)
                numpy.savetxt("sample", data, newline=" ", fmt="%d")
                sorted_arrays += 1

# Slave
else:
    # Ask for work
    data = numpy.empty(ARRAYSIZE, dtype=numpy.int32)
    while True:
        print "[Worker %d] asking for work" % rank
        comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=0, tag=ASK_FOR_WORK_TAG)
        print "[Worker %d] sent request for work" % rank

        comm.Recv([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], source=0, tag=MPI.ANY_TAG, status=status)

        if status.Get_tag() == WORK_TAG:
            print "[Worker %d] got work" % rank

            print "[Worker %d] is sorting the array" % rank
            data.sort()
            print "[Worker %d] finished work. Sending it back" % rank
            comm.Send([data, ARRAYSIZE, MPI.INT], dest=0, tag=WORK_DONE_TAG)
        elif status.Get_tag() == DIE_TAG:
            print "[Worker %d] DIE DIE DIE" % rank
            break
        else:
            print "[Worker %d] Doesn't know what to to with tag %d right now" % (rank, status.Get_tag())
```